# WIth and without semicolon - SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have some simple code, but not sure why I'm getting the error.

Here is the error:

SQL Error [933] [S1000]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
SELECT *
FROM CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS
WHERE TEST_NAME = Medical Consent
```

I have also tried it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS
WHERE TEST_NAME = Medical Consent;
```

Same error on both tries.

Comment: You need single quotes around what looks like a string constant.

Comment: Like this: SELECT *
FROM CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS
WHERE TEST_NAME = "Medical Consent";

Comment: I've tried that and get: SQL Error [904] [S0022]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: "Medical Consent": invalid identifier

Comment: Single quotes, not double: SELECT * FROM CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS WHERE TEST_NAME = 'Medical Consultant'; Whether or not you need the semi-colon will depend on what tool you are using to submit the query. Some clients append the semi-colon automatically and that can generate the same error if you also put one in.

Comment: Thanks for both of your comments. It worked with the single quote. This is all a new process for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `Test_Name` is a string field. You need to put quotations around the query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM CLIENT_SCREENING_TOOLS
WHERE TEST_NAME = 'Medical Consent'
```

The semicolon may or may not be required depending on which program is executing the SQL code.